# Removing "Transfer To..." and "Show Converted Files" from uTorrent's context menu

Tags: gui, context-menu, utorrent

Under uTorrent version 3.1.3 (and possibly earlier), the context menu has taken on 2 new options, "Transfer To...", for moving a download to a mobile device, and "Show Converted Files", for built-in conversion. I prefer to do all my file management and conversions manually, and the options are, at best, annoying space wasters. In fact, I'm not sure these features are even available outside of uTorrent Plus, which is not something I run. Is it possible to remove them from the context menu?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no options that allow for customizing context-menus. Your “best” bet is to [request it at the forums](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewforum.php?id=2), but don’t count on it being implemented since it is a very niche request and µTorrent (still) bills itself as being tiny and free of bloat (which a setting like this would be).

Comment: Arguably, the two options are the real bloat, for me at least, and I'm willing to bet for a majority of other users too.

Comment: I stopped upgrading after 2.0.4 because the “apps”, feeds, featured content, etc. are all bloat as far as I’m concerned; however adding an option for each option would definitely be excessive.

Comment: What I was thinking is a list where you can enable/disable and reorder context menu items, that shouldn't be too bloatey. I stopped at 2.2.1 BTW, at least before version 3 the bloat could be made invisible.

Comment: *> What I was thinking is a list where you can enable/disable and reorder context menu items*   That would still be quite a bit of bloat; each and every option would requires a variable and of course an interface to manage them.

Comment: Uh, no, there would be only 1 interface, the list. I also doubt 20 integers would add all that much to the half-megabyte settings.dat file uTorrent uses.

Comment: Yes, the list would be more work and take up more space in the options dialog. And it’s not a matter of space that’s the problem, but rather the matter of numerous variables and their management (though an array or list or something *should* help simplify it). But like I said, modifying the context menu is far too niche of a request for them to bother designing, implementing, and testing it.

Comment: I’ve linked to your question at a [thread](http://forum.dev.utorrent.com/post.php?tid=105764) on the µTorrent board about 3.0’s uptake where someone else complained about the wasted space as well. Unfortunately I doubt it will change their minds.